# Why material table render fails?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-table

I'm using react and the material-table package. I noticed that already from the third rendering I have a slowdown and I don't know how to solve it. This is my code:

```
<Table
          columns={tableColumnSettings}
          data={tableData}
          exportFileName="log-table"
          rowLabel="logs"
          exportTableData={!user.restricted}
          extRows
          extSelectedRow={selectedRow}
          onRowSelection={rowSelectionHandler}
        />
```

Then in Table component:

```
const Table = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const {
    data,
    columns,
    rowLabel,
    exportFileName,
    extSelectedRow,
    extRows,
    exportTableData,
  } = props;

  useEffect(() => {
  }, [data, columns, rowLabel, extSelectedRow, extRows]);
```

In this component I call Material Table:

```
<MaterialTable
        title={title || <Typography variant="body2" style={{ color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54)' }}>{`ROWS: ${ data ? data.length : 0 }`}</Typography>}
        columns={columnsState}
        data={data}
        options={{...}}
        onRowClick={(evt, selRow) => selectHandler(selRow.tableData.id)}
      />
```

And I get this error: SBOX_FATAL_MEMORY_EXCEEDED

Comment: Do you have a component rendering itself, or an infinite render loop? Or a function calling itself? It's hard to tell from the code you posted. Chrome is running out of memory which could mean your javascript call stack is too deep

Comment: ok thanks, so it shouldn't be a library issue...

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: I solved it by changing the link from which it downloaded the material-table in the yarn.lock file. It seems to be an issue related to the version I was using... If it can help you I can write the link here